# iPhone 11 stimulator Autolayout constraint not working as expected

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

Here is the problem that I face. The bottom constraint I already put -100 but still in the iPhone 1 simulator still have appear a little small white gap. So what else can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Safe area`, not the `Bottom layout guide` to set your constraint to.

[image: Correct constraint]

Answer (score 1):

To make the image view take the entire screen, we need to have a top and bottom constraint between the image view and its super view. Thus what we need to do is to change `Top Layout Guide.Bottom` to `Superview.Top` and `Bottom Layout Guide.Top` to `Superview.Bottom`, and also make sure the constant value of both constraint is 0.

[image]